# T-SQL: Find Position of First a-zA-Z in a String

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a Select statement, I need to strip leading and trailing commas from one column.
It has values like:

```
,,Value1,Value2,,,,
```

There are no spaces between the commas.

I have tried using CharIndex to find the first occurrence of [a-zA-Z] but I don't know how to make that work.

Here's an example of my Code:

```
Select CustID, SaleDate, TargetColumn, CharINDEX('a-z', TargetColumn) [Position]
```

Every row in the [Position] column returns a 0.

I was hoping to be able to locate the first and last instance of [a-zA-Z] and then remove everything before and after those positions, respectively.

I appreciate that this may have been asked before, but I was not able to find tsql code that I can use in a Select statement.

I'd appreciate any help/pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry. The column in question can also have a string of commas between actual values, Eg: ,Food Resources,,,,,,,,,Department of Human Services,, The string is created by me in SQL that concatenates values from multiple columns and puts an empty string followed by a comma when no value is found for a particular column. Perhaps that is where I should do the 'cleanup'.

Comment: To answer the question [as stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What makes you think that "A character expression containing the **sequence** to find." _(Emphasis mine.)_ as documented for [`CharIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) _expressionToFind_ means that the _sequence_ might be interpreted as a _pattern_ when that is what you prefer?

Comment: @Talay Can you edit the Question and add your expected outcome please. As below Answer shows, You can get the index of the [a-z][A-Z] using PATINDEX() But not sure what result you want to see. If you provide the expected outcome, we can come up with solutions. Thanks

Comment: The correct answer would be that you shouldn't mess around with delimited strings in the first place. Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 1):

If you *... need to strip leading and trailing commas from one column ...* and you use SQL Server 2017+, `TRIM()` is an option:

```
SELECT TRIM(',' FROM TargetColumn) AS TargetColumn
FROM (VALUES (',,Value1,Value2,,,,')) t (TargetColumn)
```

But, if you want to make more complicated parsing (as mentioned in the comments *... the column in question can also have a string of commas between actual values ...*), a JSON-based approach (with appropriate transformations and string splitting) is a possible solution (SQL Server 2016+ is needed). The idea is to split the text, remove the empty substrings and then aggegate the parts again:

```
SELECT TargetColumn = (
   SELECT STRING_AGG([value], ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key]))
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(TargetColumn, ',', '","'), '"]'))
   WHERE [value] <> ''
)
FROM (VALUES 
  (',,Value1,Value2,,,,'),
  ('Food Resources,,,,,,,,,Department'),
  ('No commas')
) t (TargetColumn)
```

Result:

```
TargetColumn
-------------------------
Value1,Value2
Food Resources,Department
No commas
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first occurrence of A-Z you need ‘PATINDEX’ not ‘CHARINDEX’.

```
PATINDEX('%[a-z]%' TargetColumn)
```

To find the last position you could go with

```
LEN(TargetColumn)-PATINDEX('%[^,]%', REVERSE(TargetColumn))
```